# i am inserting a lot of records into a large table, should I remove the indices until I am finished?

Tags: mysql

I am importing a lot of data (something like 75 million inserts) into a MySQL database with a few different tables.

I have indexes on a lot of columns. Should I remove them while I do the inserts and just add them back after it is done? Will that have a significant impact on performance?

I get the feeling the import has slowed down now that I have imported a few hundred thousand records, and I suspect the indexes might be case.

Would any more information be useful?

Comment: Just try it out. Time the insert without the indexes + time to build the indexes vs inserting with the indexes present. (Careful if your data is not clean and some of the indexes back unique constraints.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no yes/no answer for that

- The most important point being: If the table is used while importing,
  do **not** disable the indices: Just imagine a few simple queries
  falling back to full table scan, after you have inserted 74 million
  records.
- Closely realted: Can you make sure, the table is not needed after being filled, but the indices not yet built?

If you can do the insert on a completly "cold" table, I'd drop the indices and rebuild them later.

Comment: the tables wont be used until I finish importing the data. Would it be safe to drop the indices without stopping the import? I've already started...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly. You need to remove the indexes before importing large amount of records. Otherwise it will not only take a long time to import, but it will also make the existing indexes heavily fragmented. You will have to rebuild the index anyway to restore optimal performance.

If you remove the indexes before doing the import, then import will be faster. After the import, create the indexes again and then the indexes will be created fresh and they will have no fragmentation and the search performance will be faster as well.